# Disable Hover effect for announcement webpart

Tags: web-part, css

It may sound simple, but I`m not able to find anything relevant that can help to disable Hover Effect for Announcement Webpart Page. Looking for the CSS code that I can set on the Homepage and the Announcement page that Hover effect is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to edit the list view that you are currently using for the announcement list. Edit the view and look for the option **Tabular View** and uncheck "Allow individual item checkboxes". No more hover effect.

Comment: I`ve uncheck "Allow individual item checkboxes". However, hover effect still persist. Additional information, Style set to default. Any alternate option?

Comment: My fault, change the view style to Basic Table, and you should be without the hovering effect. But still disable the tabular view to get rid of the selectable checkboxes